# Update AJAX results in a div (recall)

Tags: javascript, html, ajax

I'm trying to update a div via AJAX. I'm working on an online browser based MMORPG. I was using simple links and href to the PHP pages i wanted, but the problem was with the history, it was really piling up...
So anyway, i got to the conclusion that AXAJ is better.
I', having a problem updating my div with the attack.php results... It fights only once. I click the button the second time and nothing happens.
I've used the Web Developer Web Console and i got this

> [14:47:51.167] TypeError: document.getElementById(...) is null @ stickmaniagame.com/test/indexajaxtest.php:40

and on my indexajaxtest.php line 40 is

```
    document.getElementById("gif").style.visibility="visible";
```

the first time i click, i have no problem, but the second time, i get this error and nothing happens...

Here is my code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<?  include('includes/config.php');
?>
<script type="text/javascript">
var creatureId;
var i;
function attack(creatureId)
{
    document.getElementById("gif").style.visibility="";
    document.getElementById("gif").src="images/anim.gif";
    document.getElementById("attackbtn").style.visibility="hidden";
    setTimeout(function(){myTimer(creatureId)},2000);
}

function myTimer(creatureId)
{
    var x=document.getElementById("mySelect");
    var xmlhttp;
    document.getElementById("gif").style.visibility="hidden";
    document.getElementById("img").innerHTML="";
    document.getElementById("attackbtn").style.visibility="";

    if (window.XMLHttpRequest)
      {xmlhttp=new XMLHttpRequest(); }
    else
      {xmlhttp=new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");}

    xmlhttp.onreadystatechange=function()
      {  if (xmlhttp.readyState==4 && xmlhttp.status==200)
        {
            document.getElementById("battle").innerHTML=xmlhttp.responseText;
        }
      }
    xmlhttp.open("GET","attack.php?creature="+creatureId,true);
    xmlhttp.send();
}

function attack2()
{
    document.getElementById("gif").style.visibility="visible";
    document.getElementById("gif").src="images/anim.gif";
    document.getElementById("attackbtn").style.visibility="hidden";
    setTimeout(function(){battle()},2000);
}

function battle()
{
    var x=document.getElementById("mySelect");
    var xmlhttp;
    document.getElementById("gif").style.visibility="hidden";
    document.getElementById("img").innerHTML="";
    document.getElementById("attackbtn").style.visibility="";

    if (window.XMLHttpRequest)
      {xmlhttp=new XMLHttpRequest(); }
    else
      {xmlhttp=new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");}

    xmlhttp.onreadystatechange=function()
      {  if (xmlhttp.readyState==4 && xmlhttp.status==200)
        {
            document.getElementById("battle").innerHTML=xmlhttp.responseText;
        }
      }
    xmlhttp.open("GET","click.html",true);
    xmlhttp.send();
}
function reply_click(clicked_id)
{
    creatureId=clicked_id;
    myTimer(creatureId);
}
</script>
</head>
<body>

<h1>Attack</h1>
<div id="img"><img id="gif" style="visibility:hidden"></div>
<div id="battle" style="visibility:visible;"></div>
<input id="attackbtn" name="attackbtn" type="image" src="/test/images/attack.jpg" value="Attack" onclick="attack2()" />
<form>
<div onClick="if(document.getElementById('creatures').style.visibility=='visible')
                {document.getElementById('creatures').style.visibility='hidden';}
                else{document.getElementById('creatures').style.visibility='visible';}">
Creatures:
</div>
<div id="creatures" style="visibility:collapse;">
  <?
  $creatures = mysql_query("SELECT id, name FROM creatures ORDER BY level DESC limit 5");
while($row = mysql_fetch_array($creatures))
  {
      ?>
  <div id="<? echo $row['id']; ?>" style="margin-left:100px;" onClick="reply_click(this.id);">
  <img src="images/monster.jpg" height="30px" /><? echo $row['name']; ?>
</div>
<? } ?>
</div>
<input type="button" onclick="attack2()" value="Alert index of selected option">
</form>
</body>
</html>
```

BTW, the login info for the test account is:

username: test

password: 1234

Links:

[To log in! IMPORTANT! www.stickmaniagame.com](http://stickmaniagame.com/)

[http://stickmaniagame.com/test/indexajaxtest.php the problem file...](http://stickmaniagame.com/test/indexajaxtest.php)

Comment: I would advise not trying to do Ajax from scratch. The pitfalls are numerous.  There's a reason things like jQuery exist :)

Comment: I've used only "simple" developing, I'm just 16... ha ha... but I'll try to check out what you mean, although i don't really understand...